# Solve $x^5\equiv 4\pmod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

We know about calculating  $x^2\equiv 2\pmod 7$ using quadratic residue properties in order to find out whether a solution exists or not.

I wonder is there any way to determine that $x^n\equiv k\pmod v$, where $v\ge 2$, $k\in\Bbb Z$, and $n\ge 3$?  As I asked in title:

> Solve $x^5\equiv 4\pmod 7$

Comment: Moreover,how can we solve the title without using brute force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^6\equiv1\bmod 7$, invert the exponent mod $6$:  $\;5\times5\equiv1\bmod 6$,

so $x^5\equiv4\bmod7\implies x\equiv x^{5\times5}\equiv4^5=1024\equiv2\bmod7.$

Comment: Tanner, thanks for your help

Comment: We could also solve $x^{-1}\equiv 4 \bmod 7$ by the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @hardmath thanks for your help

Comment: @J.W. Tanner what about if it were (mod 8) instead of (mod7)

Comment: @harezmi The general approach used here (which doesn't always work, mind you) is called [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem). In the case of $x^5\equiv_84$, however, it trivially has no solutions, as $x^3$ or higher powers are either odd or $0$.

Comment: as @Arthur said

Comment: @Arthur thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to determine this. Over the field $\Bbb F_7$ the [Berlekamp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) gives the factorisation
$$
x^5-4=(x^4 + 2x^3 + 4x^2 + x + 2)(x - 2).
$$
Hence $x=2$ is the solution of the equation $x^5=4$. We may rewrite this as $x\equiv 2\bmod 7$.

Comment: thanks for your help